401 Unauthorized Error with JWT Authentication in .NET 8 and Vue.js Application
I am making a small application using .NET 8 for the backend and Vue for the front.
At the moment, I have the login feature. Once the user logs in, their data loads on the "Home" screen.
I am trying to implement a login with JWT for added security and to learn how to do it since it’s a good practice in larger applications, but I am consistently encountering the 401 Unauthorized error and cannot resolve it.
In my appsettings.json file, I have the necessary parameters for JWT:
"Jwt": {
  "Key": "8D9E3B5F7C2A4E9D1F3C6A7E9B2D4C8F",
  "Issuer": "http://localhost:5251",
  "Audience": "http://localhost:8080"
}

With that key, I sign the token generated when the user logs in:
// Login method
[HttpPost("login")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] LoginDto loginDto)
{
  var user = await _context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.UserName == 
  loginDto.UserName);
            
  if (user == null || !BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(loginDto.Password, user.Password))
  {
     return Unauthorized(new { message = "Invalid username or password." });
  }

  // Create the JWT token
  var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
  var key = _configuration["Jwt:Key"];

  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
  {
     throw new InvalidOperationException("JWT Key is not configured.");
  }

  var keyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
  var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
  {
     Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(
     [
         new(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString()),
         new(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
     ]),
     Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
     SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(keyBytes), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature),
     Issuer = _configuration["Jwt:Issuer"], 
     Audience = _configuration["Jwt:Audience"]
  };
  var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
  var tokenString = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

  Console.WriteLine("Token: " + tokenString);
  Console.WriteLine("Issuer: " + _configuration["Jwt:Issuer"]);
  Console.WriteLine("Audience: " + _configuration["Jwt:Audience"]);

  return Ok(new { token = tokenString });
}

In the Local Storage, I see that the token is stored. [insert image description here]

In the Network tab, I see that the token is in the request, and the response tells me that it is invalid. [insert image description here]

I have verified that the generated token is correct on jwt.io and I see that the "Issuer" and "Audience" are correct, in addition to the user identifier I am using to log in.
On the client side, I collect the token generated on the server from the response and store it in local storage for access:
async handleSubmit() {
  try {
      const url = this.isRegistering 
      ? 'http://localhost:5251/auth/register' 
      : 'http://localhost:5251/auth/login'; 

      const response = await axios.post(url, { 
         username : this.username,
         password : this.password
      });

      if (this.isRegistering) {
          this.setMessage(response.data.message || "Registration successful! You can now log in.", false);
          this.clearFields(); 
      } else {
          const token = response.data.token;

          if(token) {
             localStorage.setItem('token', token)
             this.setMessage("Login successful!", false)
             this.login({ username: this.username })
             this.$router.push({ name: 'Home' });
          }
          else {
             this.setMessage('Login failed. Token not received', true);
          }

      }               
  } catch (error) {
      this.setMessage(error.response?.data?.message || "An error occurred. Please try again.", true);
       console.error('Error:', error.response.data);
  }
},

Once on the home page, I access that local storage from the client to retrieve the token and confirm that the user currently logged in is the correct one:
methods: {
    async fetchTasks() {
      try {
        console.log("token", localStorage.getItem("token"));
        const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:5251/api/task/upcoming', {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
            },
        });
        this.tasks = response.data;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching tasks:', error);
      }
    },
  },


And this is the backend method:
[Authorize]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TaskController(TaskManagerContext context) : ControllerBase
{
   private readonly TaskManagerContext _context = context;

   // Method to get the next 3 tasks for a user
   [HttpGet("upcoming")]
   public async Task<IActionResult> GetUpcomingTasks()
   {
      var userIdClaim = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
      if (userIdClaim == null)
      {
         return Unauthorized();
      }
      var userId = int.Parse(userIdClaim.Value);

      // Query tasks for the authenticated user
      var upcomingTasks = await _context.Tasks
          .Where(t => t.UserId == userId)
          .OrderBy(t => t.Date)
          .Take(3)
          .ToListAsync();

      return Ok(upcomingTasks);
   }

}


I have the same problem with Postman.
In my Program.cs, I have the services registered in the order they need to be:
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using backend.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Text;
using backend.Services;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Database connection
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<TaskManagerContext>(options =>
    options.UseNpgsql(connectionString));

// Add services to the container.
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

// Add controllers support
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddCors(options => {
    options.AddPolicy("AllowAllOrigins",
        builder => builder
                    .AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader());
});

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
    };
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

// Apply CORS policy
app.UseCors("AllowAllOrigins");

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
);

app.Run();


Therefore, I am not sure how to proceed. I have reviewed everything several times and I don't see anything wrong. Should I abandon the idea of using JWT because it’s not worth it in my application? Any help is welcome.

How you are passing jwt token to api? Through header?

@MayurLohite I generate the token on the server when the user logs in. If the credentials are correct, the response with Status 200 contains this token. The token is then saved in local storage to be used in every request that requires authorization, and it is sent in the request header

Its possible to share your generated JWT token?

have the same problem with Postman. -> can help us address the issue in the backend server. But reviewing your codes, we could see the method for generating the access token should work well as the token generated can be decoded successfully. Then the authorization mechanism looks good too, in program.cs you've set up it correctly. So that I'm afraid the issue occurred at return Unauthorized(); May I know that have you debug the app? And does the request went into public async Task<IActionResult> GetUpcomingTasks()?

By the way, could you pls set all thoes validation options to false and have a try again if the 401 error code is thrown by auth scheme but not from the return Unauthorized();?

@MayurLohite Mi JWT Token is:
"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJuYW1laWQiOiIyIiwidW5pcXVlX25hbWUiOiJKdWxpbyIsIm5iZiI6MTczMDIxNTAzNywiZXhwIjoxNzMwODE5ODM3LCJpYXQiOjE3MzAyMTUwMzcsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6NTI1MSIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHA6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6ODA4MCJ9.ciIAqwHLtNnKXa7t3bW5bY_R7PfRs-ZSCa_gXXbrSMA"
The one showed in the local storage image. I validated this token on jwt.io and it has the correct credentials

@TinyWang It does not reach the GetUpcomingTasks() method in the backend. It stops at the fetchTasks() method in the HomePage.vue component, just when it is about to receive the response from the server. I assume that, since authorization is not working, it stops there.
I set all the validations to false and still get the same error

Could you pls try to change "Issuer": "http://localhost:5251","Audience": "http://localhost:8080" to "Issuer": "Test.com",   "Audience": "Test.com" and test again?

@TinyWang Changing "Issuer" and "Audience" to "Test.com" does not work either

HI @julio-escudero-cuesta Try this
var userIdClaim = User.Claims.ToList();
Check if you get Claims in list?

@JulioEscuderoCuesta I create a sample using your configurations and it worked well, just like the result I reviewed. So that I'm afraid you might have some extra configuration causing the issue, or it might relate to the DB connection and authentication module. My plan for troubleshooting it is that you could comment the auth part and using hard code info just like what I shared and see whether it worked or not using Postman, then we could narrow down the issue. One more thing, do you have any other configurations like proxy/gateway/load balancor/cross orign hosting in your machine?

try to implement some middleware so we can see why are you getting that 401 first, then put breakpoint in the middleware, also if you put something like IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true; it should show some logs which part of the token validation is failing, dig deeper

Your middleware pipeline is wrong. UseAuthentication(); UseRouting(); UseAuthorization(); UseEndpoints(). Though the UseEndpoints middleware isn't  required afaik

@MayurLohite It does not matter. Since the Authorization is the problem here It does not even reach the "GetUpcomingTask()" method.

@Pieterjan That was not the issue here. I anyway tried what you suggested but the problem still remains

@TinyWang The application works just fine if I simply delete the Authorization header in the controller, so I assume I have something configured incorrectly regarding this. However, I cannot find the issue. I tried to copy and paste the little MVC app you provided in your response, but it only works for me if I omit the Authorization header. I do not have any other configuration, as you mentioned, that I am aware of. The same thing happens with Postman.
Is this what you meant by commenting out the auth part? I’m not sure I understood you there. Thank you for all the help, by the way

Thank you for your kind explanation. Firstly [Authorize] in required, otherwize the access  token makes no sense. What I mean about "auth part" is builder.Services.AddDbContext, comment this line will cause error in public class TaskController(TaskManagerContext context) , so we could delete (TaskManagerContext context) and comment private readonly TaskManagerContext _context = context;. We need to make sure the api can be accessed through postman.

If we'd already tried everything and it doesn't work even if you create a new project and used codes using hard coded data, I'm afraid we could try in another machine. It will make me take environment issue into consideration. Just like you know, when we work on production environment, there migth be a gateway in front of the app which might intercept the requset and return 401 error. .

Get confirmation from OP: the real issue is that the .csproj file included both JwtBearer and Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens. Since JwtBearer already has Tokens as an internal dependency, manually adding Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens caused a conflict. Removing the Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens refrence solved the issue.
========================
I create a new MVC app in .Net 8 as you have builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(); and app.MapControllerRoute in your app, but I can't reproduce your issue. I implement your configurations in Program.cs into my app, along with appsettings.json. I used your codes for generating access token into HomeController, I also created a TaskController as you have. You can see my codes and nuget package version I used. At least I could call the API endpoint using API tool successfully.
Could you pls comment the real authentication modules first just like what I have using hard code information, so that we could validate whether the issue is related to the authentication or other parts? My Program.cs and appsettings.json are using the same configuration as yours.
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var key = _configuration["Jwt:Key"];

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("JWT Key is not configured.");
        }

        var keyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(
            [
               new(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "asdf"),
                 new(ClaimTypes.Name, "user_name"),
            ]),
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(keyBytes), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature),
            Issuer = _configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            Audience = _configuration["Jwt:Audience"]
        };
        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
        var tokenString = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
        ViewBag.Token = tokenString;
        return View();
    }
}

[Authorize]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TaskController(TaskManagerContext context) : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly TaskManagerContext _context = context;

    [HttpGet("upcoming")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetUpcomingTasks()
    {
        return Ok("success");
    }
}

<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="8.0.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="8.0.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.26" />
</ItemGroup>



I apologize for not explaining myself clearly. The app you provided was fine. The issue was with my original app when I used the package versions from your configuration.
After further testing, I found the problem: my .csproj included both JwtBearer and Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens. Since JwtBearer already has Tokens as an internal dependency, manually adding Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens caused a conflict.
Removing the Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens refrence solved the issue!
Thanks for your time. I'll mark your response as useful cause it really helped!

Thanks a lot for sharing the real problem, I will update it into the reply : )
